# How to run project on netbeans having different (.java) files

Tags: java, netbeans, project

I just got one project of java online,but this project having multiple .java files which are use by one another,so how to run this project using netbeans

Comment: Run only the main method!

Answer (score 1):

First create a new package in your project and name it however you want.
2. Move your classes into the package you have created.
3. Change the name of your package inside the class files e.g. from"package test;" to "package newTest"
4.Then save all and run the project as one application

Answer (score 0):

you need to have all the files on one folder / package , than search for your main class and compile it

Comment: How to search main class.Thank you

Comment: a main class , is a class who has this function / method
" public static void main(String attr[])  " so you need to look for this in your files " public static void main "

Comment: sorry but can't find any main class in all files,please checkout this website where from i got all file  https://www.utdallas.edu/~ilyen/animation/Banker/MANUAL.HTM   Please.